# Open Embedded Service/Einstein Bot on Page load

Tags: api, einstein-chatbot, embedded-services, einstein-bots

I have an embedded service connected to an Einstein Bot on a Customer Community Page, and on certain pages, I would like the Bot to launch automatically, rather than requiring a manual click by the user to start it. The only documentation I found was here, but given that it was rather sparse, I was hoping someone had a solution already figured out that they could share. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_einstein_bots_api.htm&type=5&release=236

Thank you!

Comment: You can make use of [Bootstrap Embedded Chat](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Embedded Chat bootstrap API should allow you to start a bot conversation.
From [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/embedded_services_web_bootstrap_chat.htm),

> This API provides developers with a quick Chat setup that skips the static help button stage, loading all the necessary dependencies, bootstraps, and opens the chat application on your website with one call.
>
> The result of using this API is the same for a customer clicking the standard "Chat With an Expert" button. If you have pre-chat enabled, it surfaces the pre-chat form. If you’ve disabled pre-chat, it sends a chat request and surface the waiting state.

I've reached out to the Salesforce product developement team to check if the  Bots API would overlap in functionality with the Embedded Chat bootstrap API and will update this thread as I have more details.

Comment: It is not recommended to use Bots API, but more go with indeed bootstrapping, or even better use Automated Invites. The API is really meant to integrate other 3rd party channels with our Bot, and launch it from anywhere in that case. API in this use-case would be too much overheard, especially as we already have out of the box options.